# SQL Error: ORA-00904: invalid identifier during table creation

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

The tables `customer` and `orderInfo` will create just fine on their own, but the others will not and throw the error.

```
CREATE TABLE customer (
customerID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
firstName VARCHAR2 (30) NOT NULL,
lastName VARCHAR2 (30) NOT NULL,
address VARCHAR2 (60),
city VARCHAR2 (30),
state VARCHAR2(20),
zipCode CHAR (5),
country VARCHAR2 (50),
phone CHAR (10),
email VARCHAR2 (30) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
username VARCHAR2 (20) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
password VARCHAR2 (20) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE orderInfo (
orderID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
customerID NUMBER REFERENCES customer (customerID),
orderDate DATE,
shipDate DATE
);

CREATE TABLE orderDetail (
orderDetailID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
orderID NUMBER REFERENCES orderInfo (orderID),
productID VARCHAR2 (10) REFERENCES product (productID),
price NUMBER (7,2),
quantity NUMBER (CHECK > 0)
);

CREATE TABLE product (
productID VARCHAR2 (10) PRIMARY KEY,
categoryID VARCHAR2 (10) REFERENCES categoryInfo (categoryID),
productName VARCHAR2 (40),
productDescription VARCHAR2 (100),
unitPrice NUMBER,
picture BLOB,
);

CREATE TABLE categoryInfo (
categoryID VARCHAR2 (10) PRIMARY KEY,
categoryName VARCHAR (50),
description VARCHAR2 (100),
);
```

Comment: Tables need to be defined before they can be used for foreign key references.

Comment: You shouldn't be using `CHAR`. All it does is add blank spaces on the end of each value for no good reason, wasting space and leading to comparison bugs. The standard string type is `VARCHAR2`. Also you don't need to repeat the datatype when defining columns as foreign keys, as they will inherit it from the referenced parent column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very close. Your errors were:

1. Tables specified in incorrect order. For a foreign key reference to be valid the table referred to must already exist:

   - `product` must be created before `orderDetail`
   - `categoryInfo` must be created before `product`
   - `customer` must be created before `orderInfo`
   - So a reasonable creation order for your tables is: `customer`, `categoryInfo`, `orderInfo`, `product`, `orderDetail`
2. The last field in each of `product` and `categoryInfo` had a trailing comma which needed to be removed.
3. The check constraint on `orderDetail` was improperly specified. It should be

   `quantity NUMBER CHECK(quantity > 0)`

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/49ee9)

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

- Remove the extra comma!
- Don't use `VARCHAR` but `VARCHAR2`.

It should look like:

```
CREATE TABLE categoryInfo (
categoryID VARCHAR2 (10) PRIMARY KEY,
categoryName VARCHAR2 (50),
description VARCHAR2 (100)
);
```

By the way, you need to make sure you create the tables in the correct order. Otherwise it will fail when one table references another that doesn't yet exist. The creation order should be:

1. customer
2. orderInfo
3. categoryInfo
4. product
5. orderDetail

Comment: Thanks, I should have checked that as it makes perfect sense... I have just been beating my head off my desk lol!